# Check notification in regular time interval and noitify user if notification is present

Tags: push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications, uilocalnotification

Im using Big Picture Notification for notifying.Here I need to check the database whether any new message is present or not....if present then a notification must be send.Can anyone help me for this.`

```
    if(true1==true) 
    {            
           runnable = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
           shownotification();
           notification
           }}
       };
    }
    handler.postAtTime(runnable, interval);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

Comment: I have done the big picture notification and it works well but the notification only come when the user opens the app.My concept was to send notification if the user is logged in but this problem still exists.

Comment: You need to put up some code examples of what you have tried or no one is going to help you.